# Developing with Gtk 2.0, C code and Linux Red Hat 8: I cannot define a button's color no matter all Gtk commands. How do you define a button color?

Tags: gtk

I have tried all variations of the following code (including ...modify_fg, too):

```
gtk_widget_modify_bg (GTK_WIDGET(thisKubandToggleButton), GTK_STATE_NORMAL, &yellow);
gtk_widget_modify_bg (GTK_WIDGET(thisKubandToggleButton), GTK_STATE_PRELIGHT, &lightyellow);
gtk_widget_modify_bg (GTK_WIDGET(thisKubandToggleButton), GTK_STATE_ACTIVE, &yellow);
```

I don't know what else to try. I researched the available helps all over the Gtk community but nothing seems to help, at all.